# Proper MERV filter for Lennox ML193UH090XE48C-51

Tags: filter

We moved into a house with no filters on the furnace.  so I put 1" MERV11 in intake grates, and last night the furnace stopped and the tech said I can not use these filters but to use the cheapest filter I can find.

I think this is a cop-out answer but I cannot find anywhere in Lennox literature the max MERV for this unit.

Can anyone help me with that

Comment: That surely is bad advice. It may be true that filters with a very high MERV rating may reduce flow too much, but the cheapest ones you can find are barely filters to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunately, [the manual](https://resources.lennox.com/fileuploads/0d24f6f2-1c0a-4e6c-aa05-a329abdb1d39Lennox_ML193DF_Manual.pdf) merely states that "replacement filters must be rated for high velocity airflow". [More on that](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101847/what-is-high-velocity-furnace-filter)

Comment: Can you give us the height/width of the filter plenum in your setup? That's going to be the determining factor here...